# How will be better, returning only generated keys of inserted entities vs returning full inserted entities?

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-insert, sql-returning

I have a question, what is the best way to return data of inserted entities with auto generated keys (IDs). For example, i need to return entities back to front after inserting them into the database. I see three ways:

1. Returning only generated keys and matching them to necessary entity objects in my code manually.
2. Returning full entities and map it into appropriate entity class.
3. Do not return anything and get data back by separate select query.

Case 3 seems less effective, and i can't choose between case 1 and case 2.

P.S. I'm using PostgreSQL, if it make difference.

Comment: Return the data that you need for the application.  Don't plan a second round trip to the database if you can avoid it.

Comment: If you insert entities one by one then 1) is probably best but if you insert multiple at once I think you need to use 2) unless you can guarantee the same order of your objects in the complete flow.